# where on multiple join postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have problem when query using postgresql
I have several tables:

numbers:

| id | phone |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 08211111 |
| 2 | 08211112 |

domains:

| id | name | is_blacklisted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc.com | 0 |
| 2 | 123.com | 0 |
| 3 | 456.com | 1 |

domain_groups:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alphabet |
| 2 | numeric |

domain_group_domains:

| domain_group_id | domain_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

number_domain_history:

| number_id | domain_id | times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |

number_domain_group_history:

| number_id | domain_group_id | times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

if I want to select number by domain history where domain.is_blacklisted = 0:

```
select numbers.id from numbers
left join number_domain_history on number_domain_history.number_id = numbers.id
where number_domain_history.domain_id not in (select domain_id from domains where is_blacklisted = 1)
group by numbers.id
limit 1000
```

The problem is how I can search number by domain_group that perform same blacklist since blacklisted only available in number_domain_history?

I have try with:

```
select numbers.id from numbers
left join number_domain_history on number_domain_history.number_id = numbers.id
left join number_domain_group_history on number_domain_group_history.
where number_domain_history.domain_id not in (select domain_id from domains where is_blacklisted = 1)
group by numbers.id
limit 1000
```

But the result is not like what I expect to return, I still get data from domain_group that the domain already blacklisted.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I want to select number by domain history where
> domain.is_blacklisted = 0:

You only need three tables:

> 1. numbers
> 2. domains
> 3. number_domain_history

You can use a simple inner join:

```
select n.phone
from numbers n 
inner join number_domain_history ndh on ndh.number_id=n.id
inner join domains d on ndh.domain_id=d.id
where d.is_blacklisted=0
group by n.phone;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> phone
> 08211111
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c2234951f98096889aa87ae340600667)

> How can I perform search by times on number_domain_group_history ? ex:
> number_domains_group_history.times > 0

Simple , add another join condition.

```
inner join number_domain_group_history ndgh on ndgh.number_id=n.id


select n.phone
from numbers n 
inner join number_domain_history ndh on ndh.number_id=n.id
inner join domains d on ndh.domain_id=d.id
inner join number_domain_group_history ndgh on ndgh.number_id=n.id
where d.is_blacklisted=0
and ndgh.times > 0
group by n.phone;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1f71f4977998a8deaec201aafd6ac9a5)

Comment: but how can i perform search by `times` on `number_domain_group_history` ?  ex: `number_domains_group_history.times > 0`